# Multiple conditional rendering

Tags: reactjs

im doing a TODO list and in this tag P i would like render the 3 differents type of priority
what im doing wrong return always Low

```
<p className="text-todo italic">
  Priority: {value.priority === 1 ? (
    <span>
      hight
    </>
  ) : value.priority === 2 ? (
    <span>
      Medium
     </span>
  ) : (
    <span>
      Low
    </span>
  )}
```

Comment: the details are insufficient to reach any conclusions.

Comment: Please take some time to __properly__ write your question and ideally add a code snippet so we can take a look at your code and give a clear answer in return.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

use switch case

```
const todoType = (priority) => {
  switch (priority) {
    case 1:
      return (
        <span>high</span>
      );
    case 2:
      return (
        <span>Medium</span>
      );
    default:
      return <span>Low</span>;
  }
}

in component

<p className="text-todo italic">
  {todoType(value.priority)}
</p>
```

Answer (score -1):

Assuming you want to render a list of elements in an Array of objects (in this case TODO items) in order of priority on a page, you would need to first order your list and then sort it.

Something like this:

```js
const unorderedArray = [
    { priority: 2, todo: 'finish homework', state: 'active' },
    { priority: 1, todo: 'answer this SO question', state: 'completed' }
]

const orderedArray = unorderedArray.sort((a, b) => {
    return a.priority - b.priority
})

console.log(orderedArray)
```

Variables `a` and `b` stand for items in the list, in this case item 1 and item 2. We are then asking to compare based on the property `priority`

You can read more on the sort function on w3schools site [here](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_array_sort.asp).